# How do I input variables into a return command in a function?

Tags: javascript

I'll try to explain as best as I can because I cannot find this anywhere.

I'm making a simple dice rolling script.

```
function rollDice(number, sides) {
    return("Rolled (number) (sides) sided dice")
}
```

so when I type the command for an example rollDice(1, 5) I want it to input "Rolled one five sided dice" but I don't know how to input the (number, sides) into the return command.

EDIT: The question has been answered, I used this

```
var names = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten', 'eleven', 'twelve', 'thirteen', 'fourteen', 'fifteen', 'sixteen', 'seventeen', 'eighteen', 'nineteen', 'twenty'];

function rollDice(number, sides) {
    return("Rolled "+ names[number] +" "+ names[sides] +" sided dice");
}
```

to convert the numbers into words and to input (number, sides) into the 'return' command.

If anyone will look back at this tho, I'm having another problem, I want to input arguments of a previous function inside my new function, but it's returning an error:

```
function randomNum(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function randomDice(number, sides) {
    randomNum(+number+, +sides+);
}

randomDice(1, 5)
```

the part that gives me the error is:

```
function randomDice(number, sides) {
    randomNum(+number+, +sides+);
}
```

Thank you for the help

Comment: Which part of that are you stuck on? String formatting? Converting e.g. `1` to `'one'`?

Comment: `return("Rolled " +number +"  "+sides +" sided dice"); `

Comment: Question is not clear. Are trying to return the string with input variables?

Comment: I'm not stuck on converting 1 to one, I just need to input the (number, sides) into the return value

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Its so easy to input these parameters to the return statement just use `+` operator before and after parameters as below:-

```
function rollDice(number, sides) {
    return "Rolled " + number +  " " + sides +" sided dice";
}
```

and also you can change integers to string using `integerValue.toString()` for example `5.toString()` or for your code `number.toString()`.

Answer (score -2):

You can use [`Template Literals`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). Also you will need to have a mapping of `1 to one` and so on..

```js
function rollDice(number, sides) {
  const mapping = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six'];
  return (`Rolled ${mapping[number-1]} ${mapping[sides-1]} sided dice`);
}

console.log(rollDice(1, 5));
```